# To Fortify, what constitutes validating an integer?

Tags: c#, fortify

I'm using Fortify static code analyzer with a C#/.NET project. I'm taking an integer parameter, a year, from user input and starting a process with that:

```
        int y = int.Parse(Year.SelectedValue); //Year is a DropDownList
        if (y >= 2017 && y <= DateTime.Today.Year)
            Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(Server.MapPath("~/bin/SomeProgram.exe"), "/x:" + y.ToString()));
```

Fortify doesn't like that, throws a "Command Injection" issue:

> 1. Data enters the application from an untrusted source.
>
> In this case the data enters at get_SelectedValue() in ccc.aspx.cs at
>   line 25.    Even though the data in this case is a number, it is
>   unvalidated and thus still considered malicious, hence the
>   vulnerability is still reported but with reduced priority values.
>
> 2. The data is used as or as part of a string representing a command that is executed by the application.
>
> In this case the command is executed by ProcessStartInfo()  in
>   ccc.aspx.cs at line 28.

There are literally two possible values of input that would cause the process to start (as of this writing) - 2017 and 2018. If the if() statement doesn't count as validation for Fortify, what would?

EDIT: on top of everything, unless you explicitly opt of ASP.NET's ViewState integrity check, `DropDownList` doesn't allow values outside of the assigned range. With this in mind, I don't see why `SelectedValue` of a `DropDownList` is treated as an untrusted source in the first place.

Comment: perhaps using that as a lookup and not directly putting the value on the command line?

Comment: Lookup to self? :) Boy, that's ugly.

Answer (score 2):

Mark it as a false positive and move on.

I don't think Fortify takes the datatype into account.  You are taking the value out of a `string` to and `int`, doing validation, then using the int value not the original.  So as far as the command injection goes not an issue (in this case).

--

**What constitutes a validation?**

When it comes to Fortify, there is a difference between what constitutes validation and what will make Fortify stop reporting on it.

Unfortunately, there are some cases (as far as I have found from my time 5+ years of using Fortify) that you just cannot make it happy without writing a custom rule for the analyzer to indicate that some method is cleansing the data.

Comment: I know there's no security risk here. My question is - to Fortify, **what constitutes a validation**? An `if` statement, apparently, doesn't.